# How to mount share in pam_mount.conf.xml depending of OU

Tags: linux, pam, likewise-open

I have a Microsoft Windows domain and I want to add the ubuntu machines with Likewise-Open. There is no problem with that, but in my windows machines I have a GPO that mount a net share depending of the OU of the user that makes login into machine.

I want to have the same with the ubuntu machines and I think that maybe it can be done with pam_mount.conf.xml file

I have this configuration:

```
<pam_mount>
<volume fstype="cifs" server="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" path="Service" mountpoint="/home/likewise-open/DOMAIN/%(USER)/Service" options="nodev,nosuid" />
</pam_mount>
```

But I want to mount the share depending of the OU of the user. In example, if a user logs in machine1 and he belows to OU=marketing:

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=marketing,dc=example,dc=com
```

He must have a pam_mount.conf.xml file like this:

```
<pam_mount>
<volume fstype="cifs" server="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" path="marketing" mountpoint="/home/likewise-open/DOMAIN/%(USER)/marketing" options="nodev,nosuid" />
</pam_mount>
```

Maybe there is another better form to do this? Or it's not possible?

Thanks